# PHPMailer from is showing as Root User

Tags: php

I am using PHP Mailer to send emails and i am using SMTP

here is the code i am using:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();

            $email->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
            $email->Host       = "mail.integradigital.co.uk"; // SMTP server
            $email->SMTPDebug  = 2; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                                       // 1 = errors and messages
                                                       // 2 = messages only
            $email->SMTPAuth   = true;  // enable SMTP authentication
            $email->Host       = "mail.integradigital.co.uk"; // sets the SMTP server
            $email->Port       = 26;    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
            $email->Username   = "sending@************.co.uk"; // SMTP account username
            $email->Password   = "********";        // SMTP account password

            $email->SetFrom($result["emailfrom"]);
            $email->FromName($result["emailfrom"]);

            $email->Subject   = $result["subject"];
            $email->Body      = $result["message"];
```

but its sending and showing as from *Root User* - *root@localhost*

i know i can change this in the class.phpmailer.php file but i want to be able to set it in the code above

is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure `$result["emailfrom"]` has a value set?

Comment: yes it does have a value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the whole thing in a try catch. And initialize phpmailer with exceptions enabled

```
$email = new PHPMailer(true);
```

It looks like the default values are used. So something goes wrong when calling `setFrom()`. And it's failing silently because it returns `false` without exceptions enabled.

```
try {
  // your mail code here
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

And change the setting of email and from name to:

```
$email->setFrom($result["emailfrom"], $result["emailfrom"]);
```

`FromName` is a property not a method.

Comment: i want to be able to make it come from a name and not an email address

Comment: i have managed to make it display from an email address but just not a name

Comment: You know how email works right? You need an email address for that as well.. :) `$email->setFrom($result["emailfrom"], $result["emailfrom"]);`

Comment: that one didnt work, i tried Name, email@domain.com and email@domain.com, Name

Comment: That's how the class works. You are calling `FromName` as a method. But it's a property. You should really use `setFrom` for that.

Comment: Change your call to `$email->FromName = $result["emailfrom"];` That should work fine. Unless your SMTP server is screwing things up!

Answer (score 15):

Okay, in short:

```
$email->From = "email.address@gmail.com";
$email->FromName = "Support Team";
```

This worked out for me.

Comment: Yes worked for me as well, and this seems more in keeping with the basic example found on http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial  
which does not user getters and setter.

    $mail->From     = "from@example.com";
$mail-AddAddress("myfriend@example.net");

Comment: Wrong approach. Should call the method, because it provides validation.

Answer (score 3):

class.phpmailer.php file contains the  "var $FromName = 'Root User';" section which can be changed to "Desired Name" from "Root User" and have your job done.

Comment: That's okay, I guess if you will always only have one reply address and don't want to know why things are not functioning correctly. When something is not operating right, I tend to want to know the cause. I have been using PHPMailer for quite some time, and this has suddenly cropped up. The version has not changed. Obviously, it is me, but I'm struggling with putting my finger on it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your form when you are getting the 1. **email** and 2. **name** it should look like this

1. `<input type="text" name="emailfrom">`
2. `<input type="text" name="namefrom">`

Inside your php code it should look like this.

`$mail->setFrom($_POST['emailfrom'],$_POST['namefrom']);`

I was having the same issue when I was using these settings on infinityhost I hope this helps.

````
$mail->Port = 587; // Which port to use, 587 is the default port for TLS security.
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Which security method to use. TLS is most secure.```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was sending only the first parameter to `setFrom()`, as `name <email>`.

`setFrom()` did not know how to parse that construction.

Changing to two separate parameters solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$mail->setFrom('here email add of sender','here name of the sender');
```

First parameter is the email addres if it is empty or not a valid email address it will show as ROOT user while sending mail using php mailer

Answer (score 0):

For PHPMailer Version: 5.1

This worked for me:

```
    $mail->SetFrom('no-reply@example.com', 'Name From');
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your phpmailer.php, changing:

```php
if($mail->Send()){
```

to:

```php
if (mail($_POST["email"], 
         $_POST["subject"],
         $_POST["message"],
         $_POST["sender"])) {
  echo'Email Sended';
}
```

```
         *HTML* 
<form action="phpmailer.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="sender" value="From: Support Team<Support@email.com>"/>
</form>
```

`if ($mail->Send()) {` is set to Auto root, if you send email and From is not declared at the same time.