# my mail script shows my cpanel username to email recipients - security risk

Tags: php, email, security, cpanel

I use Namecheap host (shared one). When my php mail script is sending users a registration email, they are shown my Sender details (aka username at hosting webserver) which actually is a security risk - because it exposes the cpanel username and also the webserver name.

If I use SMTP and Gmail account to send email, again it is a security risk because it allows use of brute force to access either cPanel or gmail account (taking into consideration that Namecheap cpanel does not offer 2FA and also when using gmail details it's not possible to enable 2FA, too, at authentication of SMTP). Or is it possible?

What are the solutions for such situation?

Comment: you can change the from name in smtp code.

Comment: for example,
$email->From = "email.address@gmail.com";
$email->FromName = "Support Team";

Comment: check this if you find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437544/phpmailer-from-is-showing-as-root-user

Comment: @Mit.agile I changed that From name, but cannot change the Sender (it seems to be broadcasted by the server itself in order to fight spam), however I cannot even display my own domain name instead. It always show Sender as cPanelusername @ webserver-150 dot com (or alike). That is shown in headers of emails received by users (and in their webmail pages too), not in the simple display. "From" changing works, "Sender" changing doesn't !

Comment: $email->From did u type email or name here ?

Comment: $email->From should have email address.

Comment: I changed both of them, because the script I use initially had Root User (as a name) and something else as email address. It is displayed nicely at From (something as Website Admin <no-reply at mydomain.com >) but Sender is the same as I explained earlier.

Comment: try to create a new email address in your server using cpanel and use this email in $email->From.

Comment: something like noreply@yourwebsite.com and use $email->From = 'noreply@yourwebsite.com';

Comment: $mail->Sender="mailer@example.com"; // indicates ReturnPath header

Comment: also tell me which php script or lib you are using to send emails so that i can have a better idea and can dig into it

Comment: Yes, I tried countless times to simply change it into my own no-reply email address. I will post here the php script which I use (the source of it).

Comment: Part of it is below : class.phpmailer.php
.---------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|  Software: PHPMailer - PHP email class                                    |
|   Version: 2.0.4                                                          |
|   Contact: via sourceforge.net support pages (also www.codeworxtech.com)  |
|      Info: http://phpmailer.sourceforge.net                               |
|   Support: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/                     |

Answer (score 0):

While user name leakage is a security issue, the fastest and safest approach to mitigate it is to set a very secure password.

If you password is 50 random characters, it will not be brute-forced - wether your username is known or not. If your username is public or leaked, it is a good rule of thumb to add as many random characters to your password as your username was long. This way, you maintain the same level of entropy.

Attacks that allow users to bypass authentication when knowing only the username are rare.